# Polymer 2.0 + Webpack dependency issue

Tags: javascript, inheritance, webpack, polymer

I need help with Webpack + Polymer bundling. I have superclass, that contains API calls and contains promises configuration:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.js">

class Base extends Polymer.Element {
    constructor() {
      super();

      Promise.config({cancellation: true});
    }
```

Then I have an application file, with component, which class is inherited from superclass Base, that was specified as entry point in `webpack.config.js, here is my Webpack config:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'inherited-component': './some-inherited-component.html'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: __dirname + '/dist'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'bower_components'],
    descriptionFiles: ['package.json']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: [{loader: 'babel-loader'}],
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      use: [
        {loader: 'babel-loader'},
        {loader: 'polymer-webpack-loader'}
      ]
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin('./dist'),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: './bower_components/webcomponentsjs/*',
      to: './'
    },
    {
      from: './manifest.json',
      to: './'
    }]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: './inherited-component.html',
      chunks: ['inherited-component'],
      title: ''
    })
  ]
};
```

But for some reason, bluebird is not included, because I get an error `Promise.config is not a function`. Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: For some reason Promise.config declaration in bundled `some-inherited-component.js` file is placed after calling this function